# Lambda expression groupby on single column and fetch all column orderby count

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

Here my query is I have a list with repeated data and on that, I want to do `groupby` clause on `FName` column and display in order by descending of a count and display all record of that particular list

```
        List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 1, FName = "John", Age = 23, Sex = 'M' });
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 2, FName = "Mary", Age = 25, Sex = 'F' });
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 3, FName = "John", Age = 28, Sex = 'M' });
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 4, FName = "Amber", Age = 23, Sex = 'M' });
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 5, FName = "Kathy", Age = 25, Sex = 'M' });
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 6, FName = "Lena", Age = 27, Sex = 'F' });
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 7, FName = "John", Age = 28, Sex = 'M' });
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 8, FName = "Kathy", Age = 27, Sex = 'F' });         

        var dup1 = empList
          .GroupBy(x => new { x.FName })
          .Select(group => new { Name = group.Key.FName, Count = group.Count() })
          .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);

        foreach (var x in dup1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Count + " " + x.Name);
        }
```

**From the above code I am getting output like this:**

[image]

**But what i actually want is like this:**

[image]

Comment: And what if any people with the same name have a different sex or age?

Comment: hi, Servy that not issue, actually that I have given dummy data list.

Comment: In the Select clause, you can include the Age and Gender from the first record in the Group.

Comment: So you just want `Age` and `Sex` data from the first record in each group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want the group count, and then the information about the first item in the group. If that's the case, then you can simply use `GroupBy` to group the items, and then in your output just capture and display the information for the first item in the group:

```
var groups = empList.GroupBy(e => e.FName).OrderByDescending(group => group.Count());

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    var first = group.First();
    Console.WriteLine($"{group.Count()} {first.FName}\t{first.Age} {first.Sex}");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
.Select(group => new
{
    Name = group.Key.FName, 
    Count = group.Count(),
    Age = group.First().Age,
    Sex = group.First().Gender
});
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for *why* it works.